# Rails, displaying model's name in view instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, associations

I would really appreciate some help on this.

I have relationships such as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ideas, :class_name => 'Challenge', :foreign_key => 'creator_id'
  has_many :contributions, :class_name => 'Challenge', :foreign_key => 'contributor_id'

class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :contributor, :class_name => 'User'
```

My problem is being able to display the name rather than the id of a user in the views for the challenge model.

In the console I can assign a challenge to @challenge and then enter

```
@challenge.creator.name
```

which returns the name of the creator, perfect. But when I try to put this in my view it  returns undefined method 'name'.

I think that the closest to the correct thing that i've done is making the relevant part of my challenges index view say creator, instead of creator_id:

```
<tr><% @challenges.each do |challenge| %><tr>
<td><%= challenge.creator %></td>
```

but instead of returning the creator name in the view which is what I want, it returns the following output:

```
#<User:0x007fe1b81c20b8>
```

Could anybody please explain why a field is displayed like this and how I can output the user's name in my view.

My Challenges controller index action is just:

```
@challenges = Challenge.all
```

Comment: Just pointing out. "it returns the following output:" There's no output following that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it must be displaying the object itself. challenge.creator is the object and not the name of the creator.

Replace

```
<td><%= challenge.creator %></td>
```

With

```
<td><%= challenge.creator.try :name %></td>
```

Comment: When I do that the output is:   undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I guess I need to change something to make the name accessible?

Comment: You have not set the creator for the challenge object (challenge.creator = user_obj1). So, the creator is nil for this challenge and nil object doesn't have a name method. <td><%= challenge.creator.try :name %></td>.   Try this code. It will o/p the name of the creator if a creator exists. Else, it will o/p nothing without crashing.